# Why do Auntie Em and Uncle Henry not have counterparts in Oz?

Tags: character, the-wizard-of-oz

In the film version of *The Wizard of Oz* several characters play two roles - one from the scenes in Kansas before the tornado, and a second as a counterpart character in Oz. Miss Gulch is the Wicked Witch of the West, the three farmhands are the Scarecrow, Tinman, and Lion, and Professor Marvel is the Wizard of Oz. The only characters from Kansas who do not have counterpart roles are Auntie Em and Uncle Henry. Is there a particular symbolic reason for this?

Comment: You are attempting to ask why injecting the dream into the script where it was not in the book without rewriting the entire plot results in a less than expected result.

Answer (score -2):

Neither Dorothy nor Toto had alternates in Oz and it wasn't established in the film that they HAD to have alternate versions of themselves. 
Ultimately, it stands to reason that the writers realized that to impart the moral of the story only required Scarecrow, Tin Man, Lion, and Professor Marvel.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange. While your answer might be helpful, it would benefit from a source to confirm where in the film it is established that ever single person had to have a counterpart? Just because some people do, doesn't mean everyone has to unless this is explained in exposition or by the executive producers. In addition the film is based on source material.

Comment: And the witch, obviously...